# Joint probability of bivariate discrete

Tags: probability, statistics

The number of people who enter a car dealership, X, is either 1, 2 or 3 each with probability 1/3.  The number of people who buy, Y, given that X people enter the dealership is binomial with n=x and p=1/2. 
Find the joint probability mass function of (X, Y). 

I tried to construct a table of p(X,Y):
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 &1&2&3\\
\hline
0 & \frac13(\frac12)=\frac16 & \frac1{12} & \frac1{24} \\
1 & \frac16 &\frac1{12}  & \frac1{24} \\
2 & 0 & \frac1{12} & \frac1{24}\\
3&0&0&\frac1{24}
\end{array}
$$
But the values add up to be 3/4, which does not make sense (should be 1)
Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because the distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is binomial with $n = X$ and $p = 1/2$, this means, for example, that $$\Pr[Y = 1 \mid X = 2] = \binom{2}{1} (1/2)^1 (1 - 1/2)^{2-1} = \frac{1}{2},$$ not $1/4$ as your table would imply.  Your error appears to be the neglect of the binomial coefficient in the conditional distribution.  Similarly, we would have $$\Pr[Y = 2 \mid X = 3] = \binom{3}{2} (1/2)^2 (1 - 1/2)^{3-2} = \frac{3}{8},$$ not $1/8$.  Another way to see that your table can't be correct is to observe that your table would suggest $Y \mid X$ is **uniform**, when it should not be so.